# What is the verb to express "a person walks like a drunk after he spins around and around"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Ok, After my child spins around and around, he often feels dizzy & walks like a drunk and almost falls.

What is the verb to express "**a person walks like a drunk after he spins around and around**"? can we say "**You are walking like a sloppy drunk**"? or any other ways to express it?

> [Sloppy Drunk](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sloppy%20Drunk)
>
> Someone who after indulging in large amounts of alcohol exhibits one
>   or more of the following characteristics; loosing all sense of
>   balance, loss of any sort of mental filter on their mouth, uses
>   excessive cursing, performs lewd dancing, and is usually covered in
>   whatever alcohol they were drinking. These people are usually fun to
>   be around first but in the end are just an embarrassment. Joe - "Yo
>   man did you see that girl Megan last night?" Steve - "Yea dude she is
>   such a sloppy drunk, she bumped into me and spilled beer all over
>   herself and then blamed it all on me."

Comment: The adjective _sloppy_ isn't necessary to convey the idea - just "walk like a drunk" or "drunken man".

Comment: Please remember that young children are not English speakers.  

What is your aim here?  To teach your child what the word "drunk" means?  Why not just say "dizzy"?  Urban dictionary is rarely a good reference for words, and certainly not for words to teach to children.

Comment: @JamesK, I don't want to say things that sounds unnatural to him as it at affect his English expression later when he grows up.   I just want my child to speak common English structures that native speakers often say. Whenever I say something, I always ask myself whether that is an idiomatic way of saying it and whether native people say like that in that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**totter** and **stagger** are what you want, for instance:
He staggered home, drunk and intoxicated.